# synchronize widow 7 and rhel 7 time without using ntp server

Tags: linux, synchronization, window, rhel

I have two system one is local system in which window 7 is there and a server in which rhel 7 OS is there. I want to synchronize time of my local system with Server. Only SSH port 22 is open to access server. Can anyone suggest any way other that creating NTP server as post 123 is not open between two system and it is not possible to open anyhow.
As i don't have port 123 open between them i want to synchronize the window 7 and rhel 7 any other way only one time

Comment: Why don't you simply synchronize both systems against a public ntp server as it is usually done?

Comment: Apart from that you still can use an ntp server on that system, even if that port is blocked by a firewall. You can use an ssh tunnel to access it.

Comment: thanks for replying @arkascha can u explain a bit more about use of ssh tunnel for synchronization

Comment: An ssh tunnel allows to create a re-routing of any network traffic through encapsulation into an encrypted stream. In a way it allows to forward a locally accessible port to some outside client that can not directly access that port because of the network topology or package filters but that _is_ able to access the tunnel endpoint which can listen on any port number you chose. That is a general feature, not specific to synchronization. The feature is well documented, also you will find endless examples on the internet.

Comment: How synchronization could be done by using ssh

Comment: You don't use ssh. You use an ntp server and an ntp client, the only difference to a normal setup is that you tunnel the connection. So the client connects to some local port, maybe 50123, that connection is "tunneled" to the remote port 123. This is possible although that port is blocked by a firewall, since the tunnel routes the traffic through port 22 which is accessible. Take a look at the man page of the ssh command to find out about the syntax used to setup tunnels.